# Sorting a table from values out of the table but with relation

Tags: mysql, yii2

In my database, each user can submit 4 types of rates for each course.

I have a table named `course` and this table has a column named `id`.

I have another table named `rate_type` to record 4 types of the rate that user can submit

```
-------------
| id | type |
-------------
```

I have another table named `rate` to record to record user's rate submission with the following structure

```
----------------------------
| id | user_id | course_id |
----------------------------
```

And I have another table named `rate_value` to record my user's rate value for each course and for each rate type with following structure:

```
----------------------------------
| id | rate_id | value | type_id |
----------------------------------
```

the `course_id` in `rate` has relation with `id` in `course` table.
`user_id`'s relation in `rate` is not important.
`rate_id` in `rate_value` has relation with `id` in `rate` table.
`type_id` in `rate_value` has relation with `id` in `rate_type` table.(But it is not important because rate type isn't inmportant for the course, juse sum of the rates are important).

now I want to sort the `course` table from highest rate to lowest but the values of rate are in `rate` table and each course have many records in `rate` table and for sorting courses, I should sum all of the rate's for that specific course in the `rate_value` table and sort the courses by rates sum of each course.

```
$query = Course::find()
                        ->alias("t")
                        ->where(["t.deleted" => 0])
                        ->joinWith([
                             "rate"
                        ]);
```

What should I add to `$query` to complete this query as defined.

This the raw sql query I want to run with yii2 Model

```
SELECT t.id, t.title, SUM(rate_value.value) FROM `course` `t`
LEFT JOIN rate
ON rate.course_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN rate_value
ON rate_value.rate_id = rate.id
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY SUM(rate_value.value) DESC
```

UPDATE1:
This query is working correctly but when I join somthing else to this query, this will return a larger number for SUM

Comment: I would recommend nailing down the raw MySQL query first, then trying your hand at the yii2 code.

Comment: Can you show declarations of relations in your models? Also you mixed `rate` with `rank` - which one is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have models relations declared as:

```
class Course extends ActiveRecord {

    public static function tableName() {
        return 'course';
    }

    public function getRates(){
        return $this->hasOne(RateValue::class, ['rate_id' => 'id'])
            ->viaTable('rate', ['course_id' => 'id']);
    }
}

class RateValue extends ActiveRecord {

    public static function tableName() {
        return 'rate_value';
    }
}
```

You can build such query by:

```
$result = Course::find()
    ->select([
        't.id',
        't.title',
        'sum' => 'SUM(rate_value.value)'
    ])
    ->alias('t')
    ->joinWith(['rates'])
    ->groupBy(['t.id'])
    ->orderBy(new \yii\db\Expression('SUM(rate_value.value) DESC'))
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

Displaying results:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo "{$row['title']} - {$row['sum']}\n";
}
```

Comment: This generates query from question by using active record. So either you query is wrong, or your relations definitions are different.